# How do I get the exit status of a command in a getline pipeline?

Tags: awk, posix, getline

In POSIX awk, how do I get the exit status (return code) from `command` **after** processing its output via `command | getline var`?  I want my awk script to `exit 1` if `command` exited with a non-zero exit status.

For example, suppose I had an awk script named `foo.awk` that looks like this:

```
function close_and_get_exit_status(cmd) {
    # magic goes here...
}
BEGIN {
    cmd = "echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; false"
    while ((cmd | getline line) > 0)
        print "got a line of text: " line
    if (close_and_get_exit_status(cmd) != 0) {
        print "ERROR: command '" cmd "' failed" | "cat >&2"
        exit 1
    }
    print "command '" cmd "' was successful"
}
```

then I want the following to happen:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk
got a line of text: foo
got a line of text: bar
got a line of text: baz
ERROR: command 'echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; false' failed
$ echo $?
1
```

According to the [POSIX specification for awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), `command | getline` returns 1 for successful input, zero for end-of-file, and -1 for an error.  It's not an error if `command` exits with a non-zero exit status, so this can't be used to see if `command` is done and has failed.

Similarly, `close()` can't be used for this purpose:  `close()` returns non-zero only if the close fails, not if the associated command returns a non-zero exit status.  (In gawk, `close(command)` returns the exit status of `command`.  This is the behavior I'd like, but I think it violates the POSIX spec and not all implementations of awk behave this way.)

The awk `system()` function returns the exit status of the command, but as far as I can tell there's no way to use `getline` with it.

Comment: +1 for the question.  refer http://docs.freebsd.org/info/gawk/gawk.info.Getline.html, you may think to use  `ERRNO` to help you to get the exit status.  `getline` returns 1 if it finds a record, and 0 if the end of the
file is encountered.  If there is some error in getting a record, such
as a file that cannot be opened, then `getline` returns -1.  In this
case, gawk sets the variable `ERRNO` to a string describing the error
that occurred.

Comment: @BMW: Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately, POSIX awk doesn't have `ERRNO`.  Also, even in gawk a command returning non-zero does not cause `getline` to return -1.

Comment: Make that http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline instead of awk.info

Comment: mawk works the same way as gawk.

Comment: gawk's behavior depends: I get 256 by `gawk 'BEGIN{ cmd="exit 1"; cmd | getline; print close(cmd)}'` with gawk version 4.1.4 (32 bit), but 1 by version 5.0.1 (64 bit).

Comment: The change was made for version 4.2 [ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is just echo the exit status from shell after the command executes and then read that with getline. e.g.

```
$ cat tst.awk    
BEGIN {
    cmd = "echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; false"

    mod = cmd "; echo \"$?\""
    while ((mod | getline line) > 0) {
        if (numLines++)
            print "got a line of text: " prev
        prev = line
    }
    status = line
    close(mod)

    if (status != 0) {
        print "ERROR: command '" cmd "' failed" | "cat >&2"
        exit 1
    }
    print "command '" cmd "' was successful"
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
got a line of text: foo
got a line of text: bar
got a line of text: baz
ERROR: command 'echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; false' failed
$ echo $?
1
```

In case anyone's reading this and considering using getline, make sure you read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline and FULLY understand all the caveats and implications of doing so first.

Comment: The only disadvantage to this approach is that processing is delayed by a line.  If `cmd` outputs text slowly and responsiveness is important (e.g., infrequent output from an intrusion detection system that should immediately trigger a firewall change or email notification), this delay could be a problem.  For applications like that, the solution in my answer might be more appropriate.  But applications like that are rare, and I'd question the use of awk with `getline` for an application like that, so the simplicity of this answer makes it better overall.

Comment: I've updated my answer to just contain that final solution. Yes, the processing is delayed by 1 line and I agree that's almost certainly fine for any reasonable awk application. If not, you can always stick some wacky strings of control chars or something around the status when it's echoed and then check for that and if not found process the current line instead of delaying it by a line.

Answer (score 2):

Not an ideal solution, but you can do:

```
"command || echo failure" | getline var; ... if( var == "failure" ) exit;
```

There is some ambiguity in that you have to select the string "failure" in such a way that command can never generate the same string, but perhaps this is an adequate workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was hoping for a more general solution, but this'll do for a quick-and-dirty script.

Comment: +1 for simplicity; a suggestion for a string not likely to be encountered in text files: `printf '\\a'`, followed by test `if(var == "\a")`

Answer (score 1):

The following is horrifically complicated, but it:

- is POSIX conformant (mostly -- `fflush()` isn't yet in the POSIX standard, [but it will be](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=634) and it's widely available)
- is general (it works no matter what kind of output is emitted by the command)
- does not introduce any processing delay.  The accepted answer to this question makes a line available only after the *next* line has been printed by the command.  If the command slowly outputs lines and responsiveness is important (e.g., occasional events printed by an IDS system that should trigger a firewall change or email notification), this answer might be more appropriate than the accepted answer.

The basic approach is to echo the exit status/return value after the command completes.  If this last line is non-zero, exit the awk script with an error.  To prevent the code from mistaking a line of text output by the command for the exit status, each line of text output by the command is prepended with a letter that is later stripped off.

```
function stderr(msg) { print msg | "cat >&2"; }
function error(msg) { stderr("ERROR: " msg); }
function fatal(msg) { error(msg); exit 1; }

# Wrap cmd so that each output line of cmd is prefixed with "d".
# After cmd is done, an additional line of the format "r<ret>" is
# printed where "<ret>" is the integer return code/exit status of the
# command.
function safe_cmd_getline_wrap(cmd) {
    return                                                  \
        "exec 3>&1;"                                        \
        "ret=$("                                            \
        "    exec 4>&1;"                                    \
        "    { ( "cmd" ) 4>&-; echo $? >&4; } 3>&- |"       \
        "    awk '{print\"d\"$0;fflush()}' >&3 4>&-;"       \
        ");"                                                \
        "exec 3>&-;"                                        \
        "echo r${ret};"
}

# like "cmd | getline line" except:
#   * if getline fails, the awk script exits with an error
#   * if cmd fails (returns non-zero), the awk script exits with an
#     error
#   * safe_cmd_getline_close(cmd) must be used instead of close(cmd)
function safe_cmd_getline(cmd,        wrapped_cmd,ret,type) {
    wrapped_cmd = safe_cmd_getline_wrap(cmd)
    ret = (wrapped_cmd | getline line)
    if (ret == -1) fatal("failed to read line from command: " cmd)
    if (ret == 0) return 0
    type = substr(line, 1, 1)
    line = substr(line, 2)
    if (type == "d") return 1
    if (line != "0") fatal("command '" cmd "' failed")
    return 0
}
function safe_cmd_getline_close(cmd) {
    if (close(safe_cmd_getline_wrap(cmd))) fatal("failed to close " cmd)
}
```

You use the above like this:

```
cmd = "ls no-such-file"
while (safe_cmd_getline(cmd)) {
    print "got a line of text: " line
}
safe_cmd_getline_close(cmd)
```

Comment: You answered your own question?

Comment: @aks: Yeah, I figured it out after I asked it.  My solution is not very pretty so I'm hoping a more clever answer comes along.  Answering your own question may seem a little strange, but it's actually encouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: What problem is the awk script trying to solve?  Perhaps it could be done directly in bash?

Comment: @aks:  I wanted to use awk's associative arrays.  (Implementing your own associative arrays in POSIX shell is possible but very difficult.)  Also, I wanted the challenge of figuring it out.  :)

Comment: bash associative arrays are actually very easy to use. See this: https://gist.github.com/aks/8574081

Comment: @aks: bash isn't available on the platform I'm targeting.  And if I were to go with a non-POSIX language, I'd probably pick Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `mktemp` command, you could store the exit status in a temporary file:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
file=$(mktemp)
finish() {
    rm -f "$file"
}
trap 'finish' EXIT
trap 'finish; trap - INT; kill -s INT $$' INT
trap 'finish; trap - TERM; kill $$' TERM

awk -v file="$file" 'BEGIN{
    o_cmd="echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; false"
    cmd = "("o_cmd "); echo $? >\""file"\""
    print cmd
    while ((cmd | getline) > 0) {
        print "got a line of text: " $0
    }
    close(cmd)
    getline ecode <file; close(file)
    print "exit status:", ecode
    if(ecode)exit 1
}'
```